# Multifile output in gnuplot without replot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to make a gnuplot script template that would produce eps and png outputs. The goal is that when I want to make a new plot I just copy the template, set formats, labels etc., and plot what I need to plot.

The easy way is:

```
set terminal postscript eps
set output 'output.eps'
plot sin(x)
set output

set terminal pngcairo
set output 'output.png'
replot
set output
```

However when using multiplot, the replot command only replots last plot, so I would have to reenter mutliplot for the second output and make additional changes that I would prefer to avoid.

What I would like to achieve would be something like this, in gnuplot pseudocode:

```
set terminal 1 postscript eps
set output 1 'output.eps'
set terminal 2 pngcairo
set output 2 'output.png'

plot ...

set output 1
set output 2
```

So that both output files are produced in parallel, and the only thing that I would have to edit are lines between opening and closing output files.

I could make a bash script to make it work the way I want, but I prefer to handle it within the gnuplot script, so that it would be portable, and in single file.

Is there a way to do it like this?

Answer (score 2):

Consider a loop:

```
do for [FILETYPE in "png eps"] {
 set output "plot.".FILETYPE
 set term FILETYPE
 plot x**2
 set output
}
```